# Preventing Display of Post Gallery when on Homepage

Tags: wordpress

I would like to prevent the post's gallery from displaying when the post is listed on the homepage.

I'm thinking it will utilize `add_filter` and `apply_filter` when post in on homepage.

You can add a gallery to posts by clicking the add media button.  You can select existing images or upload additional images that will create a gallery within the post.  This embeds a shortcode in `$post['content']` that looks like `[gallery ids="37,38,39,40,41,42]`.

The issue is that by default it displays when the post is included on homepage as well as the individual post itself.

**Update:** This is what I am doing right now to achieve the requirement. I suspect there will be a more elegant way.

```
        <div class="entry-content">
        <!-- Begin Post Content -->
                    <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
                    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'faceboard' ) ); ?>
                    <?php else : // Filter Gallery ShortCode out ?>
                    <?php 
                        $content = '';
                        $content = get_the_content(); 
                        $content = preg_replace('/\[gallery\sids="[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*,?"\s?(royalslider="\d")?\]/s',"",$content);
                        echo wpautop( $content, 1);
                    ?>
                    <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        <!-- End Post Content -->
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'faceboard' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: Can you explain better, by code/reference/snapshot, what is `post's gallery`?

Comment: *Edited original question

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file or to a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615) (better, as you can disable it without touching the theme).

The filter `post_gallery` is used to create your own gallery, and the `$content` parameter comes empty by default. If it returns empty, the original `[gallery]` shortcode is processed.
Here, we are using a *dummy* empty value, so the filter is tricked into thinking that we are passing some actual gallery content, but it's just a white space.

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'disable_home_galleries_so_17635042', 10, 2 );

function disable_home_galleries_so_17635042( $content, $atts )
{
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
    if( is_home() )
        return '&nbsp;';

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you brasofilo - this does hide the gallery on the home page but it also hides any text that is associated with the post as it only returns &nbsp;

Comment: @Upworks, this filter **doesn't touch** the post content. It simply manipulates the [`[gallery]`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L671) shortcode. In my tests, it worked ok, i.e., *no gallery* in the homepage and *normal gallery* display in single posts.. Maybe some other plugin is interfering with it (?).